# Many events are registered on a single touch in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a game in which if user touches sound button and that should toggle sound on and off but with every touch many touches are registered. For this reason sound is sometimes off and sometime on.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using Gdx.input.isTouched();

The problem is that you are using that in your update or render method, and you keep your finger on the screen for more than 1 frame, and the audio changes very fast.

In your show method (or create) use

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputProcessor(...) );
```

And in the TouchDown method add your code, because that function is called just once whenever the touch is down, not every frame you are touching your screen.